# Iterate through positions of a substring in a string

Tags: python, string, search, iterator

I'm looking for the simplest way how to iterate over the positions of a substring in a string. Currently I'm using a generator for that, but I have a feeling that it's not quite Pythonian:

```
def iteratePos(haystack, needle) :
    pos = haystack.find(needle)
    while pos >= 0 :
        yield pos
        pos = haystack.find(needle, pos+1)

s = "ABC 11 ABC 111 ABC 1"
for i in iteratePos(s, "ABC") :
    print "aye bee see at", i
    # finds 0, 7, 15

for i in iteratePos(s, "1") :
    print "one at", i
    # finds 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 19
```

So, is it possible to do this as a reasonable one-liner? Or should I stick to the solution I have?

*(Note: Should there be a simple solution for the case when `needle` is just one character, I'm interested in that as well.)*

Comment: whats wrong with your iterator?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I'm not happy about a while cycle, for start. But maybe I just want to simplify simple. I only feel that this is not good :-/

Answer (score 4):

```
s = "ABC 11 ABC 111 ABC 1"

print([ind for ind,_ in enumerate(s[:-2]) if s[ind:ind+3] == "ABC"])
[0, 7, 15]
```

In a function:

```
def iteratePos(haystack, needle) :
    ln = len(needle)
    return [ind for ind,_ in enumerate(s[:-ln-1]) if haystack[ind:ind+ln] == needle]
```

Or using `yield from` in Python 3:

```
def iteratePos(haystack, needle) :
    ln = len(needle)
    yield from (ind for ind, _ in enumerate(haystack[:-ln-1]) if haystack[ind:ind+ln] == needle)
print(next(iteratePos(s,"ABC")))
0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution is fine ... but I guess you could do

```
[i for i in range(len(s)) if s[i:].startswith(needle)]
```

if you really dont like your solution

Comment: Ok, this one is quadratic, but it's a nice one, thanks :) For single letters it could be linear tho. Now I think: `[ i for i,c in enumerate(haystack) if c == needle ]` should work for letters.

Comment: You can remove the quadratic nature by passing the `start` argument to `startswith`, e.g. `[i for i in range(len(s)) if s.startswith(needle, i)]`.  That will avoid materializing all the string slices.

Comment: that's awesome I had no idea to do that